# Mercurial: qrefresh for select files

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Say I have a number of files I have changed such that when I do an hg status it comes up with something like:

```
M ../../file1
M ../../file2
M ../../file3
```

What if I only want to do a qrefresh for the changes I've made for file2 and implicitly abandon changes I've made to file1 and file3 such that they are reverted to their original state? Is there a way to do that with mercurial? I'm fairly new to the whole version control thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `hg qrefresh` will automatically include all changes, you only need to exclude certain files, and the refresh will actually drop all changes of those files from the patch. Then you can revert the files.

This refreshes everything but `file1` and `file3` in the patch (the patch now contains no changes of either):

```
hg qrefresh -X ../../file1 -X ../../file3
```

Now `file1` and `file3` still have some changes and need to be reverted:

```
hg revert ../../file1 ../../file3
```

This will change the current versions to `../../file1.orig` and `../../file3.orig`, just in case you find you need the changes again. You can also add the `--no-backup` switch and those won't be created.

You could also do this in the opposite order:

```
hg revert ../../file1 ../../file3
hg qrefresh
```

The refresh doesn't need arguments this time because it will see no changes in those 2 files compared to the parent of the working directory, and thus will disappear from the patch (refreshing the patch basically re-writes the patch). This is the way I would do it, but I also wanted to demonstrate the `-X` switch.

Check out `hg help revert` and `hg help qrefresh` for more.

Comment: it's also possible to `hg qrefresh ../../file2`

Comment: Note that this will forget all other files in the current patch.